# C++ - Difference between float and double?

Tags: c++, double

I know that double has double the amount of memory as a float value but I was wondering if anyone can dig deeper to give me an easy to comprehend explanation. I am working on a program but for some reason a one decimal place value float doesn't work whereas double does. Why?

When you change the `double maxSpecificGrowthRate`, to `float maxSpecificGrowthRate`. It runs as though it passed through my `if` statement. When I print out the value it shows as 0.2 which should have been stopped by the `if` statement.

Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    float maxDilutionRate;
    double maxSpecificGrowthRate;
    float saturationConstant;
    int substrateConcentration;

    cout << "Enter maximum specific growth rate (per hour): ";
    cin >> maxSpecificGrowthRate;

    if (maxSpecificGrowthRate <= 0.2 || maxSpecificGrowthRate >= 0.7)
    {
        cout << "The maximum specific growth rate is not between 0.2-0.7 g/L. Terminating program..." << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Patrick M'Bongo Oh, so by using float, the "empty" spaces are actually occupied by "garbage" giving it a slightly larger value than what is inputted?

Comment: No. `double` has the same fundamental properties as `float`. Whether you are using `float` or `double`, An irrational number like `.1` will have some "garbage", at some point. The only difference is that with a `double`, the garbage starts "later".

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik I see, thanks for the reply! I'm just going to use double from now on. I don't mind my files being a tiny bit larger.